# aria2c save download result table to a file

Tags: aria2

I'm downloading multiple links using `aria2c` using a list of links. At the end of the download run, aria2c outputs a summary table on the terminal like so:

```
Download Results:
gid   |stat|avg speed  |path/URI
======+====+===========+============
1d11bc|OK  |    23KiB/s|/mnt/72B627...
```

I want to:

1. Make the table show the original links from where the download happened
2. Save this table to a file.

In the docs all I've found is [`--download-result=<OPT>`](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#cmdoption-download-result) which might help towards 1 but I can't find anything hinting towards 2. Is there any option in aria2c to save that summary table? If not, then is there a way to capture it from terminal output but not have to capture all the other stuff?

This might be something very obvious but I'm not able to find anything for this right now. Just for completeness, i'm on an Ubuntu OS and using aria2c in the Terminal.

Answer (score -1):

With logging `--log` and `--log-level` maybe you can generate the table again.